# Использование кучи

Tags: c++, valgrind

Имеется такой код

```
int main(){
    int* p = new int[2];
    delete p;
    return 0; 
}
```

Я решил просмотреть его через valgrind. Собственно результаты такие

```
==3147== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3147==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==3147==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 72,712 bytes allocated
==3147== 
==3147== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3147==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3147==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3147==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3147==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==3147==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Есть несколько вопросов

1. Откуда появилось аж целых 2!!! запроса в кучу. Сколько всего читал, обсуждался один сискол на один нью, а тут два.
2. Почему такой объем памяти в размере 72 704 байта? Получается такой объем памяти завис в куче и всего своим делетом я освободил 74 712 - 72704 = 8 байт (у меня инт 4 байта...откуда 8 байт освобожденных, не могу понять (это размер указателя в моей архитектуре))

p.s. the value of the "allocs" doesn't depend on parameter in [ ]. I've changed it on 20 elements, and allocs are still 2

Comment: Запускайте с флагом `--track-origins=yes`, тогда valgrind напечатет стек вызовов, когда была произведена аллокация. Эти 72к наверняка были выделены где-то в блоке инициализации. Соответственно это false positive.

Comment: Используйте `delete[]` для удаления массива

Comment: @Semerkin, в подобных вопросах указывайте еще и что за OS вы используете

Comment: I've read that Valgrind is used only in *nix. Thats why OS wasn't written

Answer (score 2):

Вы же удалили только указатель на массив:

```
delete p;
```

а надо сам массив со всеми элементами:

```
delete[] p;
```

Золотое правило: после [`new[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new%5B%5D/) всегда [`delete[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete%5B%5D/).

Comment: Только "и" явно лишнее.

Comment: Да, теперь лучше :)